# using minimum amount of bits to create collision bitmask from Collision Pair List

Tags: c++, compression, bitmask

To determine whether a pair of object - `a` and `b` - can collide with each other, most physics engine (e.g. reference [1](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Collision_Filtering),[2](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering)) uses the following formula :-

```
((a.m1 & b.m2) !=0) && ((a.m2 & b.m1) !=0)
```

The `&` in the above formula is ***"and"*** bit mask operation.

If I have various types of entity, an easy way to create bit mask for them is defining **Collision Pair List**.

An example of **Collision Pair List**:-

- `player` can collide with another `player`
- `tree` can collide with `bullet`
- `tree` can collide with another `tree`
- `bullet` can collide with another `bullet`

To calculate `m1` and `m2`, I assign `m1` as `1,2,4,8,...` to every type of entity.
Finally, I do the ***"or"*** operation for each pair (see `makeItCollide()` below).

Here is the code ([coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab1fb0bc9abdce93)):-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Mask{
    public: int m1=0;
    public: int m2=0;
};
void makeItCollide(Mask& mask1,Mask& mask2){
    mask1.m2=mask1.m2|mask2.m1;
    mask2.m2=mask2.m2|mask1.m1;
}
int main(){
    Mask player;
    Mask tree  ;
    Mask bullet;
    Mask air   ;
    int run=1;
    player.m1=run;run*=2;   //1
    tree  .m1=run;run*=2;   //2
    bullet.m1=run;run*=2;   //4
    air   .m1=run;run*=2;   //8
    makeItCollide(player,player);
    makeItCollide(tree  ,bullet);
    makeItCollide(tree  ,tree);
    makeItCollide(bullet,bullet);
  //test :  
  //(tree.m1 & bullet.m2 != 0) &&  (tree.m2 & bullet.m1 != 0)  --> true
  //(player.m1 & air.m2 != 0) &&  (player.m2 & air.m1 != 0)  --> false
}
```

It works.
However, I use bits very wastefully.  (1 bit for 1 type)
It would be problematic if I have 64++ types.

**Question:**
How to calculate `m1` & `m2` from any general **Collision Pair List** to achieve minimum amount of bits?

A solution doesn't need to have full code.
In other words, just a rough guide could be very useful.

**Edit:**  (clarify according to dempzorz's comment)
One of a better solution in the above example can be :-

- `air.m1`=0 , and  `air.m2`=0
- `player.m1`=1 , and  `player.m2`=1
- `tree.m1`=2 , and  `tree.m2`=3
- `bullet.m1`=2 , and  `bullet.m2`=3

This solution uses just 2 bits for `m1` and 2 bits for `m2`.
It is also an evidence of how poor my algorithm is (4+4 bits).

Comment: you can just use `std::bitset<N>` where N is amount of entities

Comment: @Slava Thank.  I wasn't clear enough.  The underlying libraries generally has hard-coded restriction (Bullet and Box2D) that N <= 32 or 64.  I can't change that (without editing their code).   They also provided a workaround by override a virtual callback, but if possible, I don't wish to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If you want to determine one type collides with the other, you can't store that information in less than one bit.  So if you need to be restricted to < 64 bits and you want to use more than that, you would need to go to a higher level, and use types like solidObject, and emptySpace or something.  You could store it in one int instead of two though.

Comment: @cppBeginner in your case, `tree` and `bullet` collides with same group of object, so you can reduce one bit. Are you looking for this property?

Comment: @apple apple Yes, that is one of the easiest technique.    I also want to find other ways too (if it can reduce amount of bits even more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a (symmetrical) matrix of collision:

Let use `std::vector<std::bitset>` in code for simplification and instead of bitfield:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void Simplify(const std::vector<std::bitset<N>>& m)
{
    int index = 1;
     for (const auto& b : m) {
        std::bitset<4> res;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != b.size(); ++i) {
            if (b[b.size() - 1 - i]) {
                res |= m[i];
            }
        }
        if (res == b && b.count() != 1) {
            std::cout << index << "th type can be removed\n";
            return;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    std::cout << "No more simplications\n";
}
```

Let's test it with your sample:

```
const std::vector<std::bitset<4>> m4 = {
    std::bitset<4>{"1000"}, // player
    std::bitset<4>{"0110"}, // tree
    std::bitset<4>{"0110"}, // bullet
    std::bitset<4>{"0000"}, // air
};

Simplify(m4); // 2th type can be removed

const std::vector<std::bitset<4>> m3 = {
    std::bitset<4>{"100"}, // player
    std::bitset<4>{"010"}, // tree/bullet
    std::bitset<4>{"000"}, // air
};
Simplify(m3); // 3th type can be removed

const std::vector<std::bitset<4>> m2 = {
    std::bitset<4>{"10"}, // player
    std::bitset<4>{"01"}, // tree/bullet
};
Simplify(m2); // No more simplifications
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80dc298a0866b97e)

Comment: Thank.  "The symmetrical matrix" enlightens me.  I will study your logic.

Comment: After testing with a little more complex [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac2b9b1c3d9b7143), I got more feeling about it.   May your clarify rationale behind `res |= m[i];`? I think it is the heart of algorithm.  ....   I vaguely feel that in each iteration, the algorithm gradually extract "essense" of collision attribute. It gradually eliminates combine-able mask (a row & a column) because it is unnecessary.

Comment: `res |= m[i];` is a binary `or`. Idea is if one row is the combination of the others, it can be dropped and is equivalent of setting the other field (so here tree and bullet are equivalent). I limit the computation to the ones which collide with current row as it seem that self collision is the default. (Else you have to test more combination per row).